# While loop not producing the required result

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, timetable

I am trying to generate a random Timetable of a University.

Following is the definition of my class "Sections",

```
class section:
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = ""
        self.course = ""
        self.section = ""
        self.instructor = ""
```

And this is how my data looks like,

```
1
Object Oriented Programming 
CS-3B
Dr Jen 
,
2
Object Oriented Programming 
SE-3A
Dr Bilal
,
```

This all data is stored in an object of sections class in array form.
Now, all these courses are basically offered in different sections. For example, course id = 1, i.e. Object Oriented Programming is offered in **CS-3B**.

I am trying to generate a timetable based upon **sections.** For example, a timetable of section **CS-3A** which will contain all the lectures of every course offered in section CS-3A. Moreover, ***this section's timetable shouldn't have any overlapping courses on one slot***. For example, if Lecture of 1st course of Section CS-3B is being held on Monday, 1st slot then no other lecture of any other course of Section CS-3B should be held on Monday, 1st slot. Also, every course will have two lectures per week.

Also, note that I had made a **Slot** class which had following definition,

```
class Slot:
    def __init__(self,day,slot,room):
        self.day  = day
        self.slot =  slot
        self.room = room
    
    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.day} {self.slot} {self.room}'
```

To make things simplier at the start, I am keeping the room of every lecture = 1. I will change it in future according to the need.

So, to solve this issue, I came up with this code.

```
t_sections = {}
for i in sections:
    if (sections[int(i.id)-1].section[:5]) not in t_sections.keys():
        t_sections[sections[int(i.id)-1].section[:5]] = [] # Make a key for new section

    for x in range(2): # Because each course must have 2 lectures
        lst = []
        day = random.randint(1, 5)
        slot = random.randint(1, 5)
        while (Slot(day, slot, 1) in t_sections[sections[int(i.id)-1].section[:5]]): # check if day + slot already exist in the sections' timetable
            day = random.randint(1, 5)
            slot = random.randint(1, 5)
        lst.append(Slot(day, slot, 1))
        t_sections[sections[int(i.id)-1].section[:5]].append([sections[int(i.id)-1].id, lst])
```

*Please don't mind the [:5], I am only doing it because some sections are further divided like CS-1A1 and CS-1A2 but I don't want a different timetable for these further divided sections and instead want their lectures to be placed in their parent section (i.e. CS-1A) which is why I have done the [:5]*

What I am doing is creating a **dictionary**. The keys of the dictionary will contain names of all the sections and the values against every key will be a list, which will contain further lists of each lecture to be placed in that section's timetable.

Now, I used a while loop to **make sure that the newly generated random values for day and slot do not exist in the already present list for that section's timetable**. That is, if a lecture is already happening on [1, 1] then it shouldn't place another lecture on the same slot.

However, the results I get have some overlapping lectures, and I can't seem to find the reason why does it happen. *Please note that it is ok if some lectures are overlapping IF IN CASE all the slots are booked and the lecture being appeneded has no slot at all available in the whole timetable* however, I have not yet dealt this case. So, as far as my understanding is, if all lecture slots are filled (i.e. 5 * 5 = 25 slots) then the program should give error because it will never exit the While loop.

Following is the for loop I have been using to get the results of dictionary

```
for k, v in t_sections.items():
    print(k, ": ", v)
```

And this is one sample result of the dictionary,

```
CS-3B :  [['1', [4 4 1]], ['1', [1 5 1]], ['27', [4 4 1]], ['27', [3 5 1]], ['75', [4 4 1]], ['75', [3 2 1]], ['88', [3 4 1]], ['88', [5 3 1]], ['90', [5 3 1]], ['90', [5 2 1]], ['99', [2 4 1]], ['99', [1 4 1]], ['184', [1 1 1]], ['184', [5 3 1]], ['185', [5 3 1]], ['185', [5 5 1]]]
SE-3A :  [['2', [2 1 1]], ['2', [4 1 1]], ['22', [2 2 1]], ['22', [5 1 1]], ['68', [4 3 1]], ['68', [1 5 1]], ['92', [3 3 1]], ['92', [2 1 1]], ['96', [2 2 1]], ['96', [4 5 1]], ['105', [2 4 1]], ['105', [2 4 1]], ['196', [2 4 1]], ['196', [4 2 1]], ['197', [2 1 1]], ['197', [4 4 1]]]
CS-7F :  [['3', [3 4 1]], ['3', [5 5 1]], ['36', [5 5 1]], ['36', [2 3 1]]]
CS-1C :  [['4', [1 1 1]], ['4', [2 1 1]], ['97', [1 3 1]], ['97', [2 4 1]], ['111', [5 4 1]], ['111', [4 1 1]], ['139', [2 1 1]], ['139', [3 5 1]], ['140', [2 4 1]], ['140', [5 5 1]], ['141', [1 2 1]], ['141', [3 4 1]], ['142', [1 5 1]], ['142', [2 5 1]], ['143', [4 3 1]], ['143', [3 5 1]], ['144', [4 4 1]], ['144', [5 5 1]], ['145', [3 4 1]], ['145', [2 2 1]], ['146', [1 5 1]], ['146', [3 5 1]]]
CS-1D :  [['5', [2 3 1]], ['5', [1 1 1]], ['98', [2 4 1]], ['98', [5 3 1]], ['102', [5 3 1]], ['102', [3 5 1]], ['147', [5 4 1]], ['147', [2 4 1]], ['148', [5 5 1]], ['148', [2 1 1]], ['149', [5 1 1]], ['149', [3 4 1]], ['150', [1 1 1]], ['150', [2 4 1]], ['151', [2 5 1]], ['151', [4 2 1]], ['152', [2 3 1]], ['152', [1 1 1]], ['153', [4 3 1]], ['153', [2 5 1]]]
CS-7A :  [['6', [1 3 1]], ['6', [1 5 1]], ['8', [5 4 1]], ['8', [1 1 1]], ['9', [3 2 1]], ['9', [4 5 1]], ['18', [3 2 1]], ['18', [3 2 1]], ['21', [2 2 1]], ['21', [4 3 1]], ['116', [4 2 1]], ['116', [1 4 1]], ['209', [4 3 1]], ['209', [4 5 1]]]
CS-7B :  [['7', [1 5 1]], ['7', [3 4 1]], ['17', [3 4 1]], ['17', [5 5 1]], ['48', [2 1 1]], ['48', [1 1 1]], ['66', [5 5 1]], ['66', [2 2 1]], ['78', [5 3 1]], ['78', [1 4 1]]]
CS-1B :  [['10', [2 3 1]], ['10', [4 2 1]], ['93', [1 3 1]], ['93', [5 5 1]], ['122', [5 4 1]], ['122', [3 1 1]], ['131', [3 4 1]], ['131', [5 3 1]], ['132', [2 1 1]], ['132', [5 2 1]], ['133', [1 3 1]], ['133', [3 2 1]], ['134', [4 2 1]], ['134', [5 5 1]], ['135', [4 1 1]], ['135', [4 2 1]], ['136', [4 1 1]], ['136', [2 3 1]], ['137', [2 3 1]], ['137', [1 2 1]], ['138', [1 1 1]], ['138', [2 1 1]]]
CS-1A :  [['11', [1 1 1]], ['11', [1 2 1]], ['81', [4 5 1]], ['81', [5 2 1]], ['95', [3 2 1]], ['95', [5 3 1]], ['123', [2 4 1]], ['123', [4 1 1]], ['124', [4 4 1]], ['124', [5 5 1]], ['125', [1 5 1]], ['125', [5 5 1]], ['126', [2 5 1]], ['126', [1 4 1]], ['127', [1 1 1]], ['127', [3 3 1]], ['128', [1 2 1]], ['128', [1 4 1]], ['129', [2 3 1]], ['129', [1 4 1]], ['130', [3 3 1]], ['130', [3 3 1]]]
```

^Note, I have only listed few of the Sections result, and not all of the results.

Now, if you look clearly in the results, check **CS-1A**

```
['11', [1 1 1]
['127', [1 1 1]
['124', [5 5 1]
['125', [5 5 1]
```

These are overlapping lecture slots, and it shouldn't have happened. Such results can also be found in other sections timetable as well.

Can anyone help me figure out what's the problem and how can I prevent this from happening? I want unique Day + Slot **combination** for every lecture of one section.

**EDIT:** I changed my Slot Class to this,

```
class Slot:
    def __init__(self,day,slot,room):
        self.day  = day
        self.slot =  slot
        self.room = room
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self.day == other.day and self.slot == other.slot:
            return True
        return False
    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.day} {self.slot} {self.room}'
```

But now I am getting this error on this function **def **eq****,

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'day'
```

The error, I believe, is being called at this line,

```
 while (Slot(day, slot, 1) in t_sections[sections[int(i.id)-1].section[:5]]): # check if day + slot already exist in the sections' timetable
```

When it tries to compare the Slot(day, slot, 1) with the already present slot in the timetable of that section.

Comment: aside: if you find yourself writing lots of getters (`getday` etc) you either need to use properties, or just access the attributes directly (python != JS ;) )

Comment: This question is ostensibly about a while loop.  But you don't actually *post* the while loop in question, so we have *no idea* why it doesn't work...

Comment: @2e0byo Yes, I actually am a bit new in Python and have a strong background in C++ so which is why the getter functions lol. I understood it later that we could simply access those attributes directly... 

The while loop is in the code I have placed in the middle, where I am generating the random timetable for each sections. It is checking whether a lecture already exists on the randomly generated slot or not. And if it exists then generate a new day + slot, otherwise exit the while loop. Should I separate out the while loop as well in my question?

Comment: I believe that the while loop in question is not performing its functionality correctly, because in the final result, there are many overlapping lectures on a single slot... as I mentioned for the CS-1A section... This wouldn't have happened if the while loop had worked according to the logic I was trying to implement it

Comment: oh goodness, there's so much code there I actually missed it, sorry.  This could do with a massive cut btw to get down to the actual problem

Comment: @2e0byo true, I think it could do a massive cut :/ but I am just bad at explaining the problem in short words, I am sorry :/ That is the reason why I decided to actually explain everything "related" to that problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238488/discussion-between-2e0byo-and-talha-ayub).

Comment: A custom class won't have a sensible `__eq__` defined by default, which is why an `if SomeClass(...) in some_collection` won't work out of the box.

Comment: What @AKX said. `in` won't work here because without a `Slot.__eq__` method defined, the `in` is checking to see if the actual object `Slot(day, slot, 1)` is contained in the list (by comparing memory addresses)

Comment: @AJBiffl I am thankful to your responses. I get my error. I tried to make a new function in my Slot class, that is, def __eq__(self, other):  return (self.day == other.day and self.slot == other.slot), which (I believe) should do the trick for me. However, it is now giving me the error that list object has no attribute "day" on the line where I called the return. Can anyone tell me what's the problem in it? I did a little bit of search on Stackoverflow as well about it but I couldn't find any question (so far) relating to this specific problem (where function is defined within class)

Comment: That sounds like you're comparing the Slot with a list? It's hard to tell without seeing the (updated) code...

Comment: @AKX yes, I am sorry, I was just editing my post. I have now added the updated code of Slot class in the end... As per my understanding, I should be comparing the "day" of two different "Slot" objects, and not Slot with a list.

Comment: You would need to show the traceback to that error too, not just the error message itself. It sounds like you might be inadvertently doing something like `Slot(...) == lst`.

Comment: Yes, ok @AKX It's being called from the function I added in the question. I have listed out the while loop in the end, from where I believe the function def __eq__ is called

Comment: Further to @AKX's comment see my stuff about your lookups: the way you get objects is sufficiently confusing that I wouldn't be surprised if you're actually comparing against a list of lists or something of the kind.

Comment: @TalhaAyub I mean you do need to show the traceback that Python prints out for you, not just your belief of what is being called.

Comment: `lst` is a list, so `t_sections[sections[int(i.id)-1].section[:5]]` is a list of lists

Comment: Or rather, `t_sections[sections[int(i.id)-1].section[:5]]` is made of elements that look like `[sections[int(i.id)-1].id, lst]`, where the actual `Slot` object is the first element in `lst`, which itself is a list

Comment: @AJBiffl yes, I got it! It was a list, which was why it was giving an error. I made things a bit cleaner and simplier following the answer of 2e0byo and now things are working perfectly. Thanks a lot for the help and also thank you AKX for helping out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I'm not quite sure what the problem is I'm just going to explain what your algorithm *is* doing.

```
for i in sections:
...
    sections[int(i.id)-1].section[:5]
```

Sections is some kind of iterable which returns an object whose `.id` is 1 more than its index (according to your q).  So what this does is:

- lookup an object in an iterable (list?)
- calculate the position of that object (`int(i.id) - 1`)
- retrieve *the same object*

Don't do this.  Just do:

```py
for section in sections: # isn't python nice?
   ...
```

if you're doing something else with this code and I've got the wrong end of the stick, it could do with explaining.

```
day = random.randint(1, 5)
lot = random.randint(1, 5)
while (
        Slot(day, slot, 1) in 
        t_sections[sections[int(i.id)-1].section[:5]]
       ): 
       # check if day + slot already exist in the sections' timetable
       day = random.randint(1, 5)
       slot = random.randint(1, 5)
```

What this does is to check whether *the specific object you just made* exists in t_sections.  Unless you defined a `.__eq__()` method on your `Section` (or inhereted from something else which provides it) python won't know how to compare your object with other objects, and will fall back to a strict identity check (`x is y`).

Note that there's no need to do the lookup for sections every time and it would be a good deal clearer just to do:

```
current_slots = section.section # or whatever
```

Since your while loop condition is likely *never* true, the while loop will never run, and so the first (random) values for `day` and `slot` will be used, hence the overlap.

---

P.S. you suggest than an infinite while loop will throw an error.  But it won't (in any programming language I know): it will just keep going for ever.  If you want it to throw an error you need to keep track of iterations, and manually throw if you go too far.  Something like:

```
count = 0
while cond:
    if count > MAX_TRIES:
        raise Exception("Tried too hard")
    do_stuff()
    count += 1
```

Personally I *always* do this instead:

```
for _ in range(MAX_TRIES):
    if not cond:
        break
    do_stuff()
```

I've been bitten by forgetting my manual counter variable too many times, and consider that much more readable anyhow.

Comment: I got it, thank you! You are absolutely correct, I had made made the code of accessing the sections way too complex. Now, following your idea, I simply kept the day + slot in section.section type dictionary and it is working perfectly now! Thanks a ton for the help.

Comment: @TalhaAyub oh good @ incidentally your eq could be simpler: just return the condition (`self.day==other day and self.slot==other.slot`) directly

Comment: yes, that's I did in the improved version of my code. Thanks again ^_^